# Shift column of dataframe by one per ID

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe containing three columns, where the first is an ID, the second denotes a year and the third column is the value associated with the ID in that year:

```
df_in <- data.frame("ID"=c(1,1,1,1,1,1, 
                           2,2,2,2, 
                           3,3,3),
                    "yr"=c(2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006, 
                           2002,2003,2004,2005, 
                           2003,2004,2005),
                    "val"=c(1,2,3,4,5,6, 
                            4,5,6,7, 
                            7,8,9))
```

I would like to introduce a lag in my `val`-column per ID, so looking at (e.g.) `ID==1` then the value at `yr==2002` should be shifted to `yr==2001`, `yr==2003` to `yr==2002` and so on. This should be the case for all unique ID's.

The row corresponding to the last year (that now doesn't have a value due to the shift) should be deleted. We ultimately end up with

```
df_out <- data.frame("ID"=c(1,1,1,1,1, 
                            2,2,2, 
                            3,3),
                     "yr"=c(2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,
                            2002,2003,2004, 
                            2003,2004),
                     "val"=c(2,3,4,5,6, 
                             5,6,7, 
                             8,9))
```

Is there an easy way to do this in `dplyr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df_out <-
  df_in %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(yr = lag(yr)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(yr)) %>% 
  ungroup
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the requested result, you can use `do`:

```
df_in %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  do(data.frame(yr = head(.$yr, -1L), val = tail(.$val, -1L)))
```

The result:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups: ID [3]
      ID    yr   val
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  1.00  2001  2.00
 2  1.00  2002  3.00
 3  1.00  2003  4.00
 4  1.00  2004  5.00
 5  1.00  2005  6.00
 6  2.00  2002  5.00
 7  2.00  2003  6.00
 8  2.00  2004  7.00
 9  3.00  2003  8.00
10  3.00  2004  9.00
```